# Why orthogonal projection operator on tangent space of some operator determines whole operator if operator and normal are opposite direction?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Notation:

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact manifold with strictly convex boundary. The distance function $d_{g}: M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
d_{g}(x, y)=\inf _{\gamma \in \Lambda_{x, y}} \ell_{g}(\gamma)
$$
where $\Lambda_{x, y}$ denotes the set of smooth curves $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$ and
$$
\ell_{g}(\gamma):=\int_{0}^{1}|\dot{\gamma}(t)|_{g} d t
$$
Given $x \in M$, let $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(y)=d_{g}(x, y)$. For any $y \in M$ with $y \neq x$, let $\eta_{x, y}$ be the unique unit speed geodesic connecting $x$ to $y$ and let $\ell_{x, y}>0$ be such that $\eta_{x, y}\left(\ell_{x, y}\right)=y .$

Let $(M,g_1)$ and $(M,g_2)$ be two compact manifold with strictly convex boundary.
Let $f_{j}(y)=d_{g_{j}}(x, y)$ and $h_{j}=\left.f_{j}\right|_{\partial M}$ where $j=1,2$. Given any $w \in T_{y} \partial M$, if $\tau:(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \rightarrow$ $\partial M$ is a smooth curve with $\dot{\tau}(0)=w$ then
$$
d h_{j}(w)=\left.\frac{d}{d s} h_{j}(\tau(s))\right|_{s=0}=\left.\frac{d}{d s} f_{j}(\tau(s))\right|_{s=0}=d f_{j}(w)
$$
Thus $\nabla h_{j}(y)$ is the orthogonal projection of $\nabla f_{j}(y)$ to $T_{y} \partial M$.
Authors says that since $\nabla f_{j}(y)$ has unit length and points outward (i.e. $\left\langle\nabla f_{j}(y), v_{j}(y)\right\rangle \leq 0$ ), it follows that $\nabla h_{j}(y)$ determines $\nabla f_{j}(y)$.

**I understood everything but fact that how $\left\langle\nabla f_{j}(y), v_{j}(y)\right\rangle \leq 0$ and $\nabla h_{j}(y)$ is the orthogonal projection of $\nabla f_{j}(y)$ to $T_{y} \partial M$ allows to determine $\nabla f_{j}(y)$ from $\nabla h_{j}(y)$?**

Any help/hint will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is $g_j$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @ArcticChar Sorry Sir for mistake. $(M,g_1)$ and $(M,g_2)$ be two compact manifolds with strictly convex boundary. $g_1$   and $g_2$ be two metrics on same manifold $M.$